# Discord.js not sending message for a specific role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a system for a position, where you get an achievement for a position, I want to warn such a user that when he wins the position he won the achievement, but I don't know how to do it, so I improvised the command below!

```js
const client = require("../index.js")
const wait = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  const member = await message.guild.members.fetch({
    user: message.user.id,
    force: true 
  })
    var canal = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === "980553632116269080");
  
   if(!member.roles.cache.has("980553630782464068")) { 
     await member.roles.cache.get("980553630782464068")
      return message.member.send(`${client.emoji.success} We Have Added PlayStation Role`)
}
})
```

I want him to be like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocALk.jpg

Comment: Do you wanted to add the role first to a member?

Comment: No, I wanted him to say that the position was added!

Comment: `!member.roles.cache.has` === `not found` using `!` declaring that if the user doesn't have the role, it will send the message. Try removing the `!`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm wanting my bot, when it gains such a position, to notify the user, but without being the position that the bot placed!

Comment: Just told you, try removing the `!`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I removed the `!`, but it didn't work!